# Server Control SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, custom-server-controls

I've recently found some very old server control code and need to up and running.  The problem is I don't know how to connect it to the database.  Below is the SQL connection:

```
  SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(this.Page.Application["AuctionDbase"].ToString());
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

My question is do I need a `web.config` file where it can grab the connection string?  I've placed the database on a local `SQL` server but I don't know if that's the right approach.  I've never worked with Server Controls before and trying to get this deployed has been difficult!

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at the code snippet and trying to locate where the existing connection string is?
Judging by the code snippet, it doesn't look like it's in the web.config. If it was then i would expect a call to the ConfigurationManager, not Page.Application.

Search the code to see if "AuctionDbase" is being set anywhere.
It's possible that it's being set in the global.asax file if you have one.

Another possibility is in the Project options under Settings.

Comment: Hi bdhar! Thanks for the quick reply.  I did a search for "AuctionDbase" and all results came back with the same one above.

Comment: So is the problem that you do not know the password to connect to the DB? But you do have access to the DB correct?

Why not create a new user and then connect to that user. i.e. create your own new connection string.

If you have a list of users already on the DB, does someone else knows the password for the user?

Finally, if you want to continue to find out where "AuctionDbase" is  beign set, you could use a tool like AgentRansack [link](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/download) to search your disk. If you don't find it, I don't see any alternative to creating a new user.

Comment: Hello ndhar!  The issue was not the password, the connection string they provided me was incorrect so I re-created the database and fixed the string.  All is working now! Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of storing/retrieving connection details.

The connectionStrings element would be the most straightforward way to handle connection strings. The connectionStrings section is dedicated to connection strings and was introduced in .NET 2.0.

If the privacy of your connection credentials is of concern: you should use the connectionStrings section, as it can also be [encrypted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) separately from any other settings.

In the Web.config file you can add:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="connectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
  ...
<configuration>
```

for more information on connection strings you can learn more here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

and in your code you can get the connection string like this:

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: So, you say that he can not grab the connection from somewhere else? That he NEEDS a web.config? Do you live in a separate world from me? My company never stores database connections in web.config and we have our own configuration subsystem. -1 for logical fallacy - a web.config is not NEEDED, just one way to store configuration data.

Comment: @TomTom I have updated my question. The .config is one of many ways to  store/retrieve credentials, you are correct. It was a mistake on my part to give the impression the config was the `only` way.